# Removing a file that starts with a preifx using tar in Linux

Tags: linux, tar

Is it possible to remove all files that start with certain name from a compressed tarball without extracting and recreating the archive again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tar file format is a streaming format, so it would be possible to do this by reading the old file, skipping over the unwanted file(s), and copying all the data you want to keep to a new tar file. If the tar file is also compressed (eg. `.tar.gz`), then you would have to uncompress, filter, recompress, and write.

I don't know of any existing tools to do this, but it should be reasonably straightforward using the [Python `tarfile` module](http://docs.python.org/library/tarfile.html), for example.

Comment: If the tar file is not compressed, one could remove the unwanted files in-place, but it's still going to have to read and write the whole archive.

Answer (score 1):

You may post-process the `tar` stream with [tardy](http://tardy.sourceforge.net/), which can filter a tar file to remove (or rename) some files. You probably want to use the `-EXclude` option, or perhaps the `-Remove_Prefix` one. (`tardy` has case sensitive options).